How to automatically update versions of GitHub actions (with renovate)?
I use renovate as App on GitHub and it successfully updates my package.json.
I would like to have a similar feature for the action files themselves under
.github/workflows
For example a step
steps:
 - uses: actions/checkout@v3

should be updated to use current version of action:
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v4

=> Is renovate able to do so?
If yes: how to get it working/how to configure correctly to do so?
If no: is there another tool for it? Or do I need to do this manually?
(Then I exchanged manual update of package.json with manual update of *.yml)
At
https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/github-actions/
It states
"Renovate supports updating Github Actions dependencies."
but I do not understand how to activate it.
Edit
Using renovate, my renovate action run through and had green state. Nevertheless, the version of an outdated action has not been updated.
After I understood, that the versions of actions should be updated by renovate with its default configuration, I had a closer look at the log of my renovate action:
INFO: Dependency extraction complete (repository=fraunhofer-isi/micat-next, baseBranch=main)
       "stats": {
         "managers": {
           "github-actions": {"fileCount": 9, "depCount": 33},
           "npm": {"fileCount": 1, "depCount": 57}
         },
         "total": {"fileCount": 10, "depCount": 90}
       }
 INFO: Workflows update rejection - aborting branch. (repository=fraunhofer-isi/micat-next, branch=renovate/actions-setup-node-4.x)

If I interpret this correctly, renovate correctly determined, that actions-setup-node should be updated (from version 2) to version 4.
However, the update somehow got rejected.
Related:
Using the latest version of a GitHub Action
https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/28625

I assume you mean "GitHub" in the title, and not GitLab, right? For dependency updates like this one, the built-in method in GitHub is Dependabot.

This works out of the box with Renovate. Did you check logs for why it doesn't detect your workflows?

Renovate should update the version of workflow actions by default. It does not need to be explicitly enabled in the renovate configuration file.
a) Try to uninstall the renovate GitHub app and install the recent version of the App. That fixed the permission issues for me.
b) You might want to check if the access token has the workflow permission.
User => Settings => Developer Settings => Personal access tokens => Tokens (classic)

If it does not have the permissions, renovate does not show an error. The renovate action runs through and shows a warning like
INFO: Workflows update rejection - aborting branch. (repository=..., branch=renovate/actions-setup-node-4.x)

c) Also check your renovate config file for syntax errors like trailing commas. If it has syntax errors, it might not be applied.
Also see:
https://docs.renovatebot.com/security-and-permissions/#global-permissions
https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/19390

As an alternative to renovate you could also use dependabot. Put a file dependabot.yml directly under .github folder:
# Set update schedule for GitHub Actions

version: 2
updates:

  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      # Check for updates to GitHub Actions every week
      interval: "weekly"

https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/keeping-your-actions-up-to-date-with-dependabot#example-dependabotyml-file-for-github-actions

Sounds like you came here to promote dependabot when asking a Renovate question

How did you come to this conclusion? Does not sound constructive to me.
